# Алгоритм для поиска суммы поддерева в AVL дереве

Tags: c++, база-данных, алгоритм, дерево

Подскажите алгоритм поиска суммы в поддереве, если для него реализована только операция добавления нового значения.

Answer (score 0):

Значит, нужно реализовать любой [обход поддерева](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0) и суммировать данные по мере обхода.

Comment: По сути я так и делаю, но что делать, если я добавляю элемент, который там уже есть? Я просуммирую, а затем окажется, что такой элемент уже есть. И получается, что сумма будет лишней. Что делать в таком случае?

Comment: Я не понимаю этого вопроса. Какая связь между добавлением и суммой поддерева?

Comment: При добавлении элемента, необходимо перерасчитывать сумму поддерева

Comment: Этого не описано в вопросе. Наверное, ещё чего-то не описано.